# Broken keys on Casio Celviano AP-21 digital piano

Tags: scales, digital-piano, repair

I have a Casio electric piano with weighted keys that I bought in the year 2000.  I've loved it but now some critical keys suddenly stopped working -- just no sound at all -- from middle C down to the F below middle C.  Most of these keys are also the same ones used to change the key -- by pressing a control button and a key that corresponds to how many half steps you want to go down.  I wonder, first, whether these keys having a dual function (and therefore being probably more complicated on the back side) contributed to their breaking, and secondly, whether they can be fixed, either by me or by a professional repair person.

I've added the model number I found on the case.  I'm really interested in knowing what is wrong before I speak with a repair person.  Casio gave me two contacts but they are both on the other side of a mountain range and if possible, I want to find someone local.  But knowing what is wrong will make that easier.

Comment: We need to know the exact model number. Surely you can find it printed on the case of the piano. **What country do you live in**, and are you in an area where there are authorized repair centers, or not? Have you gone to the Casio website and looked for information on repair service? Casio has a national network of authorized repair centers in the USA and probably elsewhere. Give us more information and we can suggest help.

Comment: I would also point out that the "state of the art" of digital pianos has improved dramatically in the last 15 years. If you were to buy a new Casio piano today, you would find that it sounds much more like a real acoustic piano than the one you have now. Still, it would be prudent to look into the feasibility of repairs.

Comment: Casio Authorized Repair Centers: http://www.casio-usa.com/support/authorizedservice/

Comment: I edited to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1):

The (not ideally looking) solution that may work is to buy just a new MIDI master keyboard and connect it through MIDI interface. This may make sense if the sound generating part is high end and sophisticated so you want to keep it.

However if it is an older model, it may make sense to replace it completely even by something cheaper as electronic devices also age morally very fast.

Comment: Not sure what word you meant for "morally," but I do agree that technology advances so fast that the same $1k now will probably get you 5X the capabilities&quality in a new keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is anything further that we can do to help you here. You know the model number, you have contacted Casio to find out where authorized repair centers are. In order to get your piano repaired, you must take it to an authorized repair center.

Some keys on your piano have failed. We cannot determine which parts on your digital piano have failed by reading your description of the problem, saying "some keys don't work". In order to determine what has gone wrong, someone with experience has to disassemble your digital piano, test to find out what parts have failed, and then replace the failed parts.

Furthermore, this model is so old that it is possible that the replacement parts will not be available.

Call repair businesses on the telephone, tell them the make, model, and year of your piano, describe the problem, and ask them if they are capable of repairing such a model, and if they can obtain parts from Casio for that particular model and year. Then go from there.

As your piano has served you for 14 years, you may decide that it is time to purchase a new digital piano to replace it rather than spending money to repair the old one. The recent models of Casio [Privia](http://www.casiomusicgear.com/products/menu_privia) and [Celviano](http://www.casiomusicgear.com/products/menu_celviano) pianos are more highly-regarded than ever among keyboardists, so buying a new Casio seems like a good move.